# How can I retrigger if part from elif part?

Tags: python, if-statement, discord.py

While I was coding this discord.py command, I struck with an idea of 'easter egg' kinda part to this command.

The idea was if someone typed in **'+fact birb'**('+fact (a string)' triggers this command), it will send 'easter egg' embed first (which I have already coded in the elif part) and then send another embed that would have been sent if anyone typed **'+fact bird'** (which triggers if part).

I wanted to ask if just copy&pasting the 'if part' to 'elif part' is the **only answer** or is there any other way to fire **'if part'** from **'elif part'**.

I can accept if your answer is retriggering the entire command with input of **'+fact bird'** in elif part.

Here is the code:

```
 @command(name='fact')
    async def animal_fact(self, ctx, animal: str):
        if (animal := animal.lower()) in ('dog', 'cat', 'panda', 'fox', 'bird', 'koala'):
            fact_url = f'https://some-random-api.ml/facts/{animal}'
            image_url = f'https://some-random-api.ml/img/{"birb" if animal == "bird" else animal}'
            async with request('GET', image_url, headers={}) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    data = await response.json()
                    image_link = data['link']
                else:
                    image_link = None

            async with request('GET', fact_url, headers={}) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    data = await response.json()
                    embed = Embed(title=f'{animal.title()} fact',
                                  description=data['fact'],
                                  colour=ctx.author.color)
                    if image_link is not None:
                        embed.set_image(url=image_link)
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                else:
                    await ctx.send(f'API returned a {response.status} status.') 

        elif (animal := animal.lower()) == 'birb':
            birb_num = randrange(3)
            if birb_num == 0:
                birb_url = 'https://upload3.inven.co.kr/upload/2020/04/18/bbs/i13666922526.jpg'
            elif birb_num == 1:
                birb_url = 'https://cdn.download.ams.birds.cornell.edu/api/v1/asset/85774871/1800'
            else:
                birb_url = 'https://www.4flix.co.kr/data/file/gallery/3743818203_HLK71nSR_d2bc42b6af7e42d5a78dce28231a600a7dc10fc8.jpg'
            async with request('GET', birb_url, headers={}) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    embed_c = Embed(title = "You've been greeted by this cute birb. continue to the bird facts.",
                                    colour = 0xDAA520)
                    embed_c.set_image(url=birb_url)
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed_c)
                else:
                    await ctx.send(f'API returned a {response.status} status.')

        else:
            await ctx.send('No facts are available for that.\nfacts availabe for: dog, cat, panda, fox, bird, koala')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I could merge 'fact embed' part of the two because 'if sequence' doesn't necessarily need elif or else part. So, I wrote another 'if' below for sending extra bird image.

```
@command(name='fact')
@cooldown(3, 10, BucketType.guild)
async def animal_fact(self, ctx, animal: str):
    if (animal := animal.lower()) in ('dog', 'cat', 'panda', 'fox', 'birb', 'bird', 'koala'):
        if animal == 'birb':
            birb_num = randrange(3)
            if birb_num == 0:
                birb_url = 'https://upload3.inven.co.kr/upload/2020/04/18/bbs/i13666922526.jpg'
            elif birb_num == 1:
                birb_url = 'https://cdn.download.ams.birds.cornell.edu/api/v1/asset/85774871/1800'
            else:
                birb_url = 'https://www.4flix.co.kr/data/file/gallery/3743818203_HLK71nSR_d2bc42b6af7e42d5a78dce28231a600a7dc10fc8.jpg'
            async with request('GET', birb_url, headers={}) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    embed_c = Embed(title = "You've been greeted by this cute birb. Please continue to the bird fact.",
                                    colour = 0xDAA520)
                    embed_c.set_image(url=birb_url)
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed_c)
                else:
                    pass
            
        fact_url = f'https://some-random-api.ml/facts/{"bird" if animal == "birb" else animal}'
        image_url = f'https://some-random-api.ml/img/{"birb" if animal == "bird" else animal}'
        async with request('GET', image_url, headers={}) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                image_link = data['link']
            else:
                image_link = None

        async with request('GET', fact_url, headers={}) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                embed = Embed(title=f'{animal.title()} fact',
                              description=data['fact'],
                              colour=ctx.author.color)
                if image_link is not None:
                    embed.set_image(url=image_link)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await ctx.send(f'API returned a {response.status} status.')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly why functions exist. As a programmer, you shouldn't have duplicated code. With each use of this block of code `(go() function)` you can pass different arguments such as `birb_url` to achieve the same goal but with different functionality.

```
async def go(birb_url:str, title:str, color):
    async with request('GET', birb_url, headers={}) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            embed_c = Embed(title=title,
                            colour=color)
            embed_c.set_image(url=birb_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed_c)
            return  # some value
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'API returned a {response.status} status.')
            return  # some value
```

I  can see that your usage of `request` is a bit different within each time, so try playing with different functions. Check which lines of code can be merged into one function and which cannot.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm sorry to say that I don't think your answer was what I was looking for. And I had my solution by myself. Several hours after I have seen your answer, I came up with an conclusion which was **why not merge the two and use another if statement which will be triggered to send additional embed when '+fact birb' was the input?**
It worked out as planned so, I should say that I figured it out by....myself?
Really appreciate your help. Hope other new programmers like me get help from kind people like you.